# layout of Namevalue collection retrieval in mvc view as html table incorrect

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Referring to  the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844887/how-to-dynamically-display-a-list-of-both-name-and-value-of-a-string-boolean-pai),i tried to implement a dynamic table .but the layout/Structure of the table is wrong. The values that should be as  different rows are shown in a single row with comma in the table generated. Please check the screen shot attached.! [image]

in fact the output should look like:

**NAME**
    crocin
maxgalin
abc
bdf
         The code in the view is like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sortable" id="myTable1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (string key in Model.AllKeys)
                            {



                                <th>
                                    @key
                                    <div>@key</div>
                                </th>


                            }
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (string key in Model.AllKeys)
                            {




                                <td>
                                    @Model[key]

                                </td>



                            }
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

the NameValue collection may or may not pass more values so that the table columns can be 1 or more when dynamically created. Please help..  I want all the names to be coming in a column as different rows. TIA

Comment: PLS PLS help..Its important for me...

Comment: You need a better data structure to do what you are doing. Perhaps consider a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?